# Query a table with info from another one in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have two tables: Invoices and Clients. Each invoice have a client and each client has an expiration time for their invoices.
I want to get each invoice where the invoice date + the expiration time has passed current date.

I actualy did it with DB::select like this.

```
 DB::select('SELECT  DISTINCT  i.id,(i.invoice_date+INTERVAL \'1 day\' * invoice_expiration) as expiration_date, i.invoice_date, c.invoice_expiration, c.id as client_id, c.name, i.total, i.status, c.rut FROM invoices i, clients c, invoice_cargos ic, cargos ca WHERE i.invoice_date+INTERVAL \'1 day\' * invoice_expiration <  current_date  AND i.client_id = c.id AND i.status not in (\'PAID\')  and i.id = ic.invoice_id and ic.cargo_id = ca."id" AND i.iva = true  AND ca.stage = \'APPROVED\' order by c.name, i.invoice_date ;');
```

But I'm having trouble translating that to eloquent.

The Invoice model has the relationship to the Client one:

Invoice Model:

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class,'id', 'client_id');
    }
```

Comment: What are the models and the relations in place ?

Comment: added the relationship in the edit

Comment: You are using 4 tables in that query. to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can then start writing an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [mre] to improve it before submitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel tries to guess, by conventions, the names of the columns in the relationships. I don't think `id` should be there as the second parameter. Also, you can omit `client_id` it would be easy for Laravel to guess that relationship, so, I'd leave it like this:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
}
```

Something like this should work:

```
Invoice::select(DB::raw('DISTINCT i.id, (i.invoice_date + INTERVAL "1 day" * invoice_expiration) as expiration_date, i.invoice_date, c.invoice_expiration, c.id as client_id, c.name, i.total, i.status, c.rut'))
->join('clients as c', 'i.client_id', '=', 'c.id')
->join('invoice_cargos as ic', 'i.id', '=', 'ic.invoice_id')
->join('cargos as ca', 'ic.cargo_id', '=', 'ca.id')
->whereRaw('i.invoice_date + INTERVAL "1 day" * invoice_expiration < current_date')
->whereNotIn('i.status', ['PAID'])
->where('i.iva', true)
->where('ca.stage', 'APPROVED')
->orderBy('c.name')
->orderBy('i.invoice_date')
->get();
```

Alternatively, you can create columns in the database to store the calculated values so that you don't have to use raw SQL in your Eloquent query. For example, you could add a `expiration_date` column to the invoices table and update it with the calculated value when creating or updating an invoice. This would allow you to use a simple Eloquent query like this:

```
Invoice::where('expiration_date', '<', Carbon::now())
->whereNotIn('status', ['PAID'])
->where('iva', true)
->join('invoice_cargos as ic', 'invoices.id', '=', 'ic.invoice_id')
->join('cargos as ca', 'ic.cargo_id', '=', 'ca.id')
->where('ca.stage', 'APPROVED')
->orderBy('clients.name')
->orderBy('invoices.invoice_date')
->get();
```